# Under what circumstances do Python unittests fail to run?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a standalone Django app that I'm working on right now. You can see the code at [Github](http://github.com/foxbunny/Djassets). In one of the edits, I introduced an error that caused the source tree to be deleted. I reset to an earlier revision, and suddenly my unittests stopped working. I've tried bisecting from an earlier revision, but it turned out nothing useful.

Actually, I know for a fact that last commit that I've pushed to Github was a good one. Cloned the Github repo, and same thing: no tests are run. What could have gone wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Turns out it was a Django-specific problem. I had a models.py file in my app that wasn't part of git repo for some strange reason. Once the source tree was removed, and code from repo restored, the models.py was no longer there, so tests wouldn't run... Silly mistake.